# How to use transients domain attributes with Grails Fields Plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm trying to add the field confirm password to an user register form. This is an extract of my domain class:

```
package usuario

class Usuario {

    transient springSecurityService

    String password
    String confirmarPassword

    static constraints = {

        password blank: false, password: true, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/
        confirmarPassword blank:false, password: true, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/, validator:{ val, obj ->
            if (obj.password != obj.confirmarPassword)
                return 'usuario.password.dontmatch'
        }

    }   

    static transients = ['confirmarPassword']

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Rol> getAuthorities() {
        UsuarioRol.findAllByUsuario(this).collect { it.rol } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

`obj.confirmarPassword` is **always null** so the constraint is never accomplished.

I installed the Grails Templates as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045164/display-a-domain-transient-property-in-scaffolded-views). I changed the attribute `persistentProperties`, but it is only at _*form.gsp*, and _*form.gsp* is not used by [Grails Fields Plugins](http://grails.org/plugin/fields). Therefore, the transients attributes don't appear in the Internet Browser.

I copied the generated transients attributes of the _form.gsp to create.gsp:

```
<fieldset>
    <g:form class="form-horizontal" action="create" >

        <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: usuarioInstance, field: 'confirmarPassword', 'error')} required">
            <label for="confirmarPassword">
                <g:message code="usuario.confirmarPassword.label" default="Confirmar Password" />
                <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <g:field type="password" name="confirmarPassword" maxlength="15" pattern="${usuarioInstance.constraints.confirmarPassword.matches}" required="" value="${usuarioInstance?.confirmarPassword}"/>
        </div>

        <fieldset>          
            <f:all bean="usuarioInstance"/>
            <div class="form-actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i>
                    <g:message code="default.button.create.label" default="Create" />
                </button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </g:form>
</fieldset>
```

The transients attributes appear on the screen, but `obj.confirmarPassword` is still **null**

The last approach I thought is to modify *views_fields\default_field.gsp* to also use these transients attributes, but I didn't find how. This is [the documentation](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html). This is the content of that file:

```
<%@ page defaultCodec="html" %>
<div class="control-group ${invalid ? 'error' : ''}">
    <label class="control-label" for="${property}">${label}</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <%= widget %>
        <g:if test="${invalid}"><span class="help-inline">${errors.join('<br>')}</span></g:if>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible with [Grails Fields Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/fields)? Where are the conditions tested, on client or server side? (I think part of the checking is on client side, but all the restrictions are checked again on server side).

Comment: hmmm, shouldn't it be: `<f:field bean="${usuarioInstance}" property="confirmarPassword" />`?

Comment: The same issue with that line of code: `Property [confirmarPassword] of class [class usuario.Usuario] with value [null] does not pass custom validation` :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest versions of Grails, transient attributes are not binded with form by default. [This is the documentation of the bindable constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/bindable.html). This is how my code would become (I just added `bindable: true`):

```
static constraints = {

    password blank: false, password: true, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/
    confirmarPassword bindable: true, blank:false, password: true, size:5..15, matches:/[\S]+/, validator:{ val, obj ->
        if (obj.password != obj.confirmarPassword)
            return 'usuario.password.dontmatch'
    }
}
```

However, transient attributes are not shown with `<f:all bean="usuarioInstance"/>`, We have to add these attributes manually: `<f:field bean="${usuarioInstance}" property="confirmarPassword" />`. It is not an ideal solution. I'll keep this question open some days hoping that someone knows the answer.

**UPDATE**

In my case, the above solution didn't work either because I'm using Spring Security Core plugin. It gives the next error:

*null id in usuario.Usuario entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)*

In that case, **we have to use a [command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects)**. That **issue is described (and solved) in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370593/spring-security-core-and-custom-validator-for-a-confirm-password-field-is-possib/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Oh that i have i encountered it before .

Declaring

```
        String confirmarPassword
```

and  making it traniset it doesn't work me like this

```
        static transients = ['confirmarPassword']
```

But

```
        transient  confirmarPassword
```

As you did it for the springService...i don't now why that doesn't work and this , some one may have a better clarification ...

Comment: if I change `static transients = ['confirmarPassword']` by `transients confirmarPassword`, eclipse shows me a compiler error: _Groovy:unexpected token: transients @ line 30, column 2_

Comment: what about the second option , i hope it works ?> may declare it as   'transient confirmaPassword'

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean with second option?

Comment: transient  confirmarPassword

Comment: eclipse shows me a compiler error: _Groovy:unexpected token: transients @ line 30, column 2_. That error should be because there is also the next line of code: `transient springSecurityService`

Comment: have u removed 's' form transitents and used as transient confirmarPassword ?

Comment: You're right. I forgot to remove the s. But it didn't work. We could use `bindable: true`, but the best way to do it I think is to use a [Command Object](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/single.html#commandObjects). I promise to update my answer later.

Comment: I updated my answer (and checked it as correct). I'll be glad if it useful for somebody! :)